# Change color-depth in FFMpeg

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, color-depth

I try play video in live wallpaper using Android NDK and FFMpeg library. I was guided by:
http://ikaruga2.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/video-live-wallpaper-part-1/

Video is playing, but I am not happy with quality. Depth of color differs from the original.
How I can fix it? There are any standard methods in ffmpeg or in openGL of control color depth?